# $.ajax is not working? How i call ajax inside jQuery onclick function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am calling the ajax inside a function. The control is going inside the function but not executing ajax call it is showing 404.

[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:5080/Employee-Mybatis/employee/employee/employeeInfo 404

code is :-

```
<script>
function showEmpDetails(empid)
{
    console.log(empid);
    $.ajax({
        url: "employee/employeeInfo",
        async: false, 
        success: function(result) { 

            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

I am using this src link for ajax :-

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You don't have an available endpoint at employee/employeeInfo.  That's what 404 means.  The async message isn't relevant to the 404, it's just telling you that you're using ajax incorrectly.

Comment: It looks like you have two times `/employee` in `http://localhost:5080/Employee-Mybatis/employee/employee/employeeInfo `

Comment: Go to your Network request tab and match the url with the API url. Looks to me a URL mismatch issue.

Comment: You are right man, I am providing wrong url only. Thanks man